# Kotlin фильтрация коллекция

Tags: массивы, kotlin, коллекции

Имею два массива целых чисел:
Первый (неправильный) Wrongarray: 1, 5, 2, 7, 93, 8, 9, 3
Второй (правильный) Rightarray: 1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 3
По условию мне необходимо из первого массива убрать числа, которые превышают сумму соседних элементов (это 5 и 93 - тут просто). Решил сделать через коллекции Kotlin с предикатом. Формирую код:

```
val array = arrayOf(WrongArray)
val result = array.dropWhile { it < (it-1) + (it+1) }
```

Т.е. оставляю число, которое меньше суммы соседних чисел.[image: Код]

Компилятор выдает ошибки на логическую операцию. Что не так делаю?

Comment: Ну `dropWhile` вообще не про это, к тому же в `it < (it-1) + (it+1)` выражение `(it-1)` и `(it+1)` - это не предыдущий и следующий элемент, а просто вычитание и сложение единицы с `it`. К тому же, что делать с первым и последним элементами в `WrongArray`? У них только по одному соседу

Comment: Эх... Думал без циклов обойдусь...

Answer (score 5):

Можно и с предикатом

```kotlin
val array = intArrayOf(1, 5, 2, 7, 93, 8, 9, 3)

val filtered = array.filterIndexed { index, i ->
    when (index) {
        0, array.lastIndex -> true // Сохраняем первый и последний
        else -> i < array[index - 1] + array[index + 1]
    }
}.toTypedArray()

println(filtered.contentToString())
```

Вывод: [1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 3]

UPD: Даже ещё упростить можно:

```kotlin
array.filterIndexed { index, i -> (index == 0 || index == array.lastIndex) || i < array[index - 1] + array[index + 1] }
```

Comment: Код рабочий. Вот только загвоздка такая возникла: как тип списка преобразовать обратно в тип массив?

Comment: @Дмитрий, newList.toTypedArray(). В принципе тут изначально список и не нужен был. Отредактировал ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, без цикла по индексам Вам тут не обойтись.

Решить можно, например, так:

```
val wrongArray = listOf(1, 5, 2, 7, 93, 8, 9, 3)
val result = mutableListOf<Int>()
for (i in wrongArray.indices){
    when {
        i == 0 -> result.add(wrongArray[i])
        i == wrongArray.size - 1 -> result.add(wrongArray[i])
        wrongArray[i-1] + wrongArray[i+1] >= wrongArray[i] -> result.add(wrongArray[i])
    }
}
println(result)
```

Первый и последний элемент здесь попадают в результат в любом случае.

По поводу `dropWhile`. Из документации:

> Returns a list containing all elements except first element that satisfy the given [predicate].

То есть `dropWhile` удалит первый элемент, не соответствующий условию.

Так как `it` - это сам элемент, а не итератор, условие `it < (it-1) + (it+1)` ВСЕГДА истинно, а значит Ваш код просто удалит первый элемент из списка.

P.s. На случай, если Вам нужно фильтровать список до тех пор, пока хоть один элемент превышает сумму соседей, то можно использовать такой код:

```
    val wrongArray = listOf(1, 5, 2, 7, 50, 93, 8, 9, 3)
    var pair = Pair(wrongArray, false)
    while (!pair.second) {
        pair = filter(pair.first)
    }
    println(pair.first)
```

Где `filter`:

```
fun filter(wrongArray: List<Int>): Pair<List<Int>, Boolean> {
    val result = mutableListOf<Int>()
    for (i in wrongArray.indices) {
        when {
            i == 0 -> result.add(wrongArray[i])
            i == wrongArray.size - 1 -> result.add(wrongArray[i])
            wrongArray[i - 1] + wrongArray[i + 1] >= wrongArray[i] -> result.add(wrongArray[i])
        }
    }
    return Pair(result, result.size == wrongArray.size)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Реализовал с самым простым вариантом и он работает (спасибо за поддержку, такие вещи в документации сразу не найдешь):

```
    val array = WrongArray.filterIndexed { index, i -> (index == 0 || index == WrongArray.lastIndex) || i < WrongArray[index - 1] + WrongArray[index + 1] }

return array.toIntArray()
```